# Вырисовывание под градусом

Tags: java, graphics

Как вырисовывать, например, изображение с разворотом по градусу? Использую awt.

Пример:

[image]

Comment: Берёшь с нагибаешь. Каков вопрос таков ответ. Учись задавать вопросы грамотно. Что ты используешь для отрисовки? Android, GWT, AWT, Swing, JavaFX?

Comment: Если речь о Java2D, [идем читать доку](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html).

Comment: ну раз awt, то ссылку тебе уже дали. Очень хорошую.